Sending Notification in Microsoft Teams using Webhook Request Workflow
I had built a pipeline which scans the Keyvaults and sends a Microsoft Teams notification using Webhook(Eonos Office Webhook) incase any Key/Certificate has expired/about to Expire. And the pipeline worked perfectly, however since O365 connectors are deing depreciated, I am forced to use Microsoft Workflows to post a message from a Webhook Request.
For that I created a Workflow which 'Post to a channel when a webhook request is received' but when I replaced my current Eonos WebhookURL with the new Workflow URL, my notification layout is completely changed and I am getting more of a text than a proper notification.
This is how my notifications used to look like:

and I just replaced the URL with the new Workflow Webhook URl, I am getting the following output:

So, It is just printing the value that it is being provided.
This is my Workflow Configuration:

and this is how I am sending the Webhook request from my Powershell skript:

and this is my Send-Notification function:

I believe that I need to change the configuration of my Flow (maybe) but I am not sure. Please help me with this :')
update from 18.09.2024:
Now I am get the links (of the secrets) as a Text instead of clickable links eventhough I enabled the Code view in the message:

and this is how I am getting the notification now:

Do you know how to solve this?
when I save it in code view and refresh it and check it again, it shows me in normal mode:

this is my code, where I check secret and create the URL for it:
function Check-Secrets {
param(
    [string]$keyVault,
    [string]$globalSubscription,
    [string]$resourceGroup
)

$expiringSecrets = @()
$noExpirySecrets = @()

$secrets = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $keyVault --query "[].id" -o tsv 2>$null
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    Write-Output "Unable to access Key Vault: $keyVault"
    $global:inaccessibleKeyVaults += $keyVault
    continue
}

foreach ($secret in $secrets) {
    $secretAttributesJson = az keyvault secret show --id $secret --query "attributes" -o json
    $secretAttributes = $secretAttributesJson | ConvertFrom-Json
    $secretName = az keyvault secret show --id $secret --query "name" -o tsv
    $secretUrl = "https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault/ListObjectVersionsRBACBlade/~/overview/objectType/secrets/objectId/https%3A%2F%2F$keyVault.vault.azure.net%2Fsecrets%2F$secretName/vaultResourceUri/%2Fsubscriptions%2F$globalSubscription%2FresourceGroups%2F$resourceGroup%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.KeyVault%2Fvaults%2F$keyVault/vaultId/%2Fsubscriptions%2F$globalSubscription%2FresourceGroups%2F$resourceGroup%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.KeyVault%2Fvaults%2F$keyVault"

    if ($null -ne $secretAttributes.expires -and $secretAttributes.expires -ne '') {
        $expiryDate = [DateTime]::Parse($secretAttributes.expires)
        $oneMonthFromNow = (Get-Date).AddMonths(1)

        if ($expiryDate -lt $oneMonthFromNow) {
            $expiringSecrets += "Secret ID: [$secret]($secretUrl), Expiry Date: $expiryDate"
        }
    }
    else {
        $noExpirySecrets += "Secret ID: [$secret]($secretUrl)"
    }
}


return @{
    "ExpiringSecrets" = $expiringSecrets
    "NoExpirySecrets" = $noExpirySecrets
}

}
and this is how I called the function:
$expiringSecretsMessage = if ($expiringSecrets.Count -gt 0) { "The following secrets are expiring:<br />" + ($expiringSecrets -join "<br />") }
    $noExpirySecretsMessage = if ($noExpirySecrets.Count -gt 0) { "The following secrets have no expiry date:<br />" + ($noExpirySecrets -join "<br />") }
    $expiringCertificatesMessage = if ($expiringCertificates.Count -gt 0) { "The following certificates are expiring:<br />" + ($expiringCertificates -join "<br />") }
    $noExpiryCertificatesMessage = if ($noExpiryCertificates.Count -gt 0) { "The following certificates have no expiry date:<br />" + ($noExpiryCertificates -join "<br />") }

    Send-Notification -keyVault $keyVault -WebhookURL $WebhookURL -messageParts @($expiringSecretsMessage, $noExpirySecretsMessage, $expiringCertificatesMessage, $noExpiryCertificatesMessage)


As far as I have tested, to send clickable hyperlink as parts of your Teams message requires your context to use the valid HTML hyperlink syntax like Secret ID: <a href="URL">ALIAS</a>. Here is a sample YAML pipeline that is to generate the webhook payload with hyperlink syntax.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  myTestKV: xxxmytestkvxxx
  TeamsWebhookURL: https://xxxxxx

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMSvcCnnSub0'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $myTestKV = "$(myTestKV)" 

      # Fetch secrets using Azure CLI command
      $secrets = az keyvault secret list --id https://$myTestKV.vault.azure.net/ | ConvertFrom-Json

      $currentDate = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
      $expiringSecrets = @()
      $noExpirySecrets = @()

      foreach ($secret in $secrets) {
          $expires = $secret.attributes.expires
          if ($expires) {
              $expiryDate = [datetime]::Parse($expires)
              $daysRemaining = ($expiryDate - $currentDate).Days
              if ($daysRemaining -le 30) {
                  $expiringSecrets += $secret
              }
          } else {
            $noExpirySecrets += $secret
          }
      }

      Write-Output "expiringSecrets - $($expiringSecrets | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
      Write-Output "noExpirySecrets - $($noExpirySecrets | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

      $expiringSecretsText = ""
      foreach ($secret in $expiringSecrets) {
          $expiryDate = [datetime]::Parse($secret.attributes.expires).ToUniversalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
          $expiringSecretsText += "Secret ID: <a href=`\`"$($secret.id)`\`">$($secret.name)</a>Expiry Date (UTC): <span style=`\`'color: red;`\`'>$expiryDate</span><br />"
      }

      $noExpirySecretsText = ""
      foreach ($secret in $noExpirySecrets) {
          $noExpirySecretsText += "Secret ID: <a href=`\`"$($secret.id)`\`">$($secret.name)</a><br />"
      }

      $testMessageJSON = @"
      {
        "text": "<b>The following secrets are expiring:</b><br />$expiringSecretsText<br /><b>The following secrets have no expiry date:</b><br />$noExpirySecretsText<br />",
        "title": "Key Vault: $myTestKV"
      }
      "@

      Write-Output $testMessageJSON
      
      $WebhookURL = "$(TeamsWebhookURL)"
      Write-Host "WebhookURL - $WebhookURL"
      Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $WebhookURL -Body $testMessageJSON -ContentType 'application/json'

Sample webhook payload
{
  "text": "<b>The following secrets are expiring:</b><br />Secret ID: <a href=\"https://xxxmytestkvxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret1\">secret1</a>Expiry Date (UTC): <span style=\'color: red;\'>09/22/2024 16:00:00</span><br />Secret ID: <a href=\"https://xxxmytestkvxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret3\">secret3</a>Expiry Date (UTC): <span style=\'color: red;\'>09/30/2024 15:59:59</span><br /><br /><b>The following secrets have no expiry date:</b><br />Secret ID: <a href=\"https://xxxmytestkvxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret2\">secret2</a><br />Secret ID: <a href=\"https://xxxmytestkvxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret4\">secret4</a><br /><br />",
  "title": "Key Vault: xxxmytestkvxxx"
}




I understand your way of solving it. However, earlier it was working just by enabling the code view and with that I didnt had to change my powershell script. Do you know why is it not working anymore? I have uploaded the code where I generate the URL in my question.

Hi @SumitBhardwaj, Thanks for your reaching out. It seemed to be another Power Automate limitation that the markdown hyperlink syntax in code view only worked when the Post as parameter was set as Flow bot. To be honest I don't quite understand the behavior either, not to mention the limitation that there was no Subject parameter when the Post as parameter was set as Flow bot, since I am not so familiar Power Automate than Azure DevOps.

With that being said, hopefully you may consider using HTML syntax instead which also enables us to use more formats. See the notification sent by my updated script.

Yes that is pretty weird behavior of Power Automate. I am happy to try your solution. So in my case, I should just edit my output message like this?  $expiringSecrets += "Secret ID: [$secret]<a href=`"($secretUrl)\">, Expiry Date: $expiryDate"`

I would recommend you follow my script for a test to make sure you get the sample webhook payload. The snippet $expiringSecretsText += "Secret ID: <a href=\"$($secret.id)\">$($secret.name)Expiry Date (UTC): <span style=\'color: red;\'>$expiryDate"
uses backtick to escape ``\`` and"in the value oftext`. I found it hard to quote the correct script in the comment. TAT

Thank you very much for your help Alvin, I was able to solve it. Thank you for your time. :)


my notification layout is completely changed and I am getting more of a text than a proper notification.

I can reproduce the similar situation when using the Post message in a chat or channel action in Microsoft flow.

The cause of the issue is that the Post message in a chat or channel action will send the content as plain text format to teams by default.
To let the message show as the HTML format, you can refer to the following steps:
Step1: Add HTML tag to your message.
Step2： When use the Post message in a chat or channel action, you need to first click the option: Toggle code view and then input the required message contains HTML tag.
For example:

Result:


Thanks for your reply. If you look at my Powershell code, the message is built using different message parts variables. how can I add an HTML tag to it?

@SumitBhardwaj From the current response sample, the secret url is link type. Can you follow the steps in my answer to enable Toggle code view option and input the message? Then you can check if the secret link is correct format first. Then you need to extract the required information from the message part via MS Flow action and add specific HTML tags respectively.

I tried your steps and have added the output in my question above. Now the notification that I am getting is actually pretty close to what I need but could you please tell me how can I get the notification without the ({"text":" ","title":""}) part?

@SumitBhardwaj I can understand your requirement now. You need to remove the text and title value in the card. In this case, you need to extract the value in the json body with the additional MS flow actions. Refer to this blog: https://tomriha.com/how-to-get-a-specific-value-from-a-json-object-in-power-automate. or this blog: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/query-values-from-json-outputs-in-powerautomate/

Then you can put the output value to the  Post message in a chat or channel action

I went through the two blogs but those solutions doesnt match my problem as I am passing json message as a variable through webhook? or did I miss something?

@SumitBhardwaj I notice that you have posted a new ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78994019/sending-notification-in-teams-using-webhook-and-power-automate and Alvin has added an answer for the details. But please note: you need to enable the option :Toggle code view in message field to make sure that the body can show as html format.

yes, the solution from Alvin helped in removing the text and title value in the card. However, Now I am get the links (of the secrets) as a Text instead of clickable links eventhough I enabled the Code view in the message. Can you please look at the updated Question part

@SumitBhardwaj Sorry for the late reply. I think that you can follow the answer shared by Alvin to solve your issue.

No worries, Thank you very much for your help Kevin, I was able to solve it. Thank you for your time. :)
