Sending Notification in Teams using Webhook and Power Automate
I have a devops pipeline which scans the KeyVaults and send notification in a Teams Channel if there are any Secrets/Certificates have expired/about to expire. Since I am using the new Workflows to send notifications via Webhook Request, my Notifications are getting distorted.
This my Power Automate workflow:

Update 18.09.2024:
@Alvin I made changes like your sample but now I am not able 'text' or 'title' und dynamic contents. Do you know what is the reason for that?
this is the Powershell Function that I am using to Send notification using Webhook:
function Send-Notification {
param(
    [string]$keyVault,
    [string]$WebhookURL,
    [array]$messageParts
)

if ($null -ne $messageParts.Count -and $messageParts.Count -gt 0) {
    $message = @{
        'text'  = ($messageParts -join "<br /><br />")
        'title' = "Key Vault: $keyVault"
    }

    $messageJson = $message | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2

    try {
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $WebhookURL -Body $messageJson -ContentType 'application/json'
        Write-Output "Notification sent for Key Vault: $keyVault"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Failed to send Teams notification for Key Vault: $keyVault. Error: $_"
    }
}

}
and this the Output (Teams Notification) that I am getting:

I need to remove the text and title value in the card, my Notification should look like this:

I guess I have to extract the Message part I need and then output the value again. I did saw some blogs for it but they dont exactly match my problem.
Could you please help me to fix this or have an alternative/better solution?
Update 18.09.2024:
@Alvin I made the changes from your suggestion and I am getting the required Notification without the extra stuff. However, Now I am get the links (of the secrets) as a Text instead of clickable links eventhough I enabled the Code view in the message:
my new configuration:

and this is how I am getting the notification now:

Do you know how to solve this?
when I save it in code view and refresh it and check it again, it shows me in normal mode:


Please post your code samples as text, not images.

I have updated it.

Please try and configure Post as parameter to be User -> In the code view of the Message section, select Expressions tab, input triggerBody()['text'] then click OK


To resolve this issue, you need to reveal the hidden Subject parameter in the Post message in a chat or channel action. Afterward, set its value to the title field from your incoming webhook payload. Additionally, assign the Message parameter to the text node of the payload.
For reference, please follow the steps shown in the screenshots below:

In the Message parameter, map it to triggerBody()?['text'].
For the Subject, use triggerBody()?['title'].


These settings will correctly post the webhook content into your Microsoft Teams channel, as demonstrated.
Here's an example of how the message will appear in my Teams channel:


Thank you very much for your reply. Please for give me for asking this question, but I am  not getting the 'Advanced Parameter' option in my Flow. How can I get that?

Hi SumitBahrdwaj, Happy to work with you again. I can only see the Subject parameter when the Post As option is configured to be User or Power Virtual Agents. Would you consider using User + Subject parameters instead?

could you please look at the the image that I uploaded to my question. I made changes like your sample but now I am not able 'text' or 'title' und dynamic contents. Do you know what is the reason for that?

Hi there, I have updated my answer for your reference. Please try and input triggerBody()['text'] in the Expressions tab. It will enable the workflow to read the contents in the text node from the webhook payload.

Thanks for the solution, I am getting the required notification but However Now I am get the links (of the secrets) as a Text instead of clickable links eventhough I enabled the Code view in the message even though earlier I was getting the clckable linkes. Please see the updated question part. Thanks in Advance

Hi @SumitBhardwaj, To send clickable hyperlink in your Teams message requires your context to use the valid HTML hyperlink syntax like Secret ID: <a href="someURL">ALIAS</a><br />. Your original query in this post is how to separate the message title and text for your Teams notification. Please resolve one question at a time, otherwise, the post may be closed due to lack of focus. I have already noticed you that you posted another thread regarding the hyperlink issue in a Teams message; will post a solution to help you generate a valid webhook payload shortly after some test.

In the meanwhile, @SumitBhardwaj, Please let us know my solution to your query in this post on how to extract text and title nodes of the webhook payload works for you. Thx for the time and update.

Yes, your solution worked for extracting text and title nodes for m the notification.
